# want use google recaptcha for a magento 2 shop

Tags: magento2

I want to use for my online shop agoshop.at a recaptcha.
I used the following site: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/security/captcha/security-google-recaptcha.html?lang=en

But when I open in the admin panel Stores > Settings > Configuration.
I cannot choose Google reCAPTCHA in the Admin Panel in Security.

There I can see only 2FA.

Hope someone can help me.
kindly regards

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using Magento 2.3, and the reCaptcha option is available. Here is a developer guide to set up and configure it: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/configuration/security/google-recaptcha.html

However, you mentioned that the reCaptcha link in the Admin is not opening. The chances of this happening are low, as it should open. If it is not opening, make sure that the module is enabled or check the Magento log or browser console for any errors.

Without seeing the error, it is difficult to troubleshoot the issue. You can either share your Admin access in the chat option of Stack so that we can check it on our system, or you can share the exact issue that you are facing right now.